# Visual Studio Code autocomplete/IntelliSense not working properly for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-code

[image: Image of vscode autocomplete]
It's not displaying the properties of an array like length etc.

I'm not sure if this is a problem or this is expected behavior of VScode's autocomplete/IntelliSense.

Do I need to install any extensions to make it work?

**Edit:**
On adding `var` or `let` before `arr` the autocomplete works fine normally but inside a function it doesn't work.
[image: autocomplete inside a function]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check if the building extension **TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features** is enabled.

To check this, go to Extensions and search for `@builtin TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features`.

This should look something like this:
[![vscode][1]][1]

**Edit:**

Also, check if you choosed the right language?

- -> `CTRL (or CMD) + P`
- -> `> Change Language Mode`
- -> `JavaScript`

Another thing I noticed: You have no `var`, `let` or `const` before the variable, see stackoverflow.com/a/51962449/14401587

**Edit 2:**

IntelliSense does not know what types the parameters have for functions. But you can use the @param annotation in the comment:

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {Array} arr 
 */
function a(arr) {
    arr.
}
```

[image: img]

For variables you can also use @type:

```js
/** @type {Array} */
let a;
```

[image: img]

Comment: Yes @Daniel this is enabled but still not working.

Comment: @at-in Choosed the right language?
CTRL (or CMD) + P -> `> Change Language Mode` -> `JavaScript`

Comment: @at-in Another thing I noticed: You have no var, let or const before the variable, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51962449/14401587

Comment: on adding `let` or `var` it works fine but inside a function it doesn't work. I'll edit my question a bit to explain this

Comment: Just a suggestion @Daniel, you should add the `let`/`var` thing in your answer since this is also a problem someone else might face.

Comment: What was the answer? I get the same issue. When I jump inside a function or method, the auto-completion won't be enabled.

Comment: Thanks man, big help was actually going crazy trying to fix this.

Comment: off topic:  which font is that (Vscode)? @Daniel

Comment: @manukn I think I used [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) in the screenshots

Answer (score 5):

Go to Extensions and search for `@builtin TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features`. Try stopping and restarting this plugin and restart VS Code. Looks like a bug. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just stop the `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features`  extension, and it works fine, maybe a bug or a conflict with other extensions I think

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).